# SceneKit applyTorque

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to applyTorque to a node in my scene. The documentation states:

> Each component of the torque vector relates to rotation about the
>   corresponding axis in the local coordinate system of the SCNNode
>   object containing the physics body. For example, applying a torque of
>   {0.0, 0.0, 1.0} causes a node to spin counterclockwise around its
>   z-axis.

However in my tests it seems that Physics animations do not affect actual position of the object. Therefore, the axis remain static (even though the actual node obviously moves). This results in the torque always being applied from the same direction (wherever the z axes was when the scene was initiated).

I would like to be able to apply torque so that it is always constant in relation to the object (e.g. to cause node to spin counterclockwise around z-axis of the node's presentationNode not the position node had(has?) when the scene was initiated)

Answer (score 2):

SceneKit uses two versions of each node: the *model* node defines static behavior and the *presentation* node is what's actually involved in dynamic behavior and used on screen. This division mirrors that used in Core Animation, and enables features like implicit animation (where you can do things like set `node.position` and have it animate to the new value, without other parts of your code that query `node.position` having to working about intermediate values during the animation).

Physics operates on the presentation node, but in some cases--like this one--takes input in scene space.

However, the only difference between the presentation node and the scene is in terms of coordinate spaces, so all you need to do is convert your vector from presentation space to scene space. (The root node of the scene shouldn't be getting transformed by physics, actions, or inflight animations, so there's no practical difference between model-scene space and presentation-scene space.) To do that, use one of the coordinate conversion methods SceneKit provides, such as [`convertPosition:fromNode:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/convertPosition:fromNode:).

Here's a Swift playground that illustrates your dilemma:

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit
import XCPlayground

// Set up a scene for our tests
let scene = SCNScene()
let view = SCNView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
view.scene = scene
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 5)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
XCPShowView("view", view)

// Make a pyramid to test on
let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPyramid(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1))
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
node.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Zero // Don't fall off screen

// Rotate around the axis that looks into the screen
node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1, w: 0.1), impulse: true)

// Wait a bit, then try to rotate around the y-axis
node.runAction(SCNAction.waitForDuration(10), completionHandler: {
    var axis = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0)
    node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(x: axis.x, y: axis.y, z: axis.z, w: 1), impulse: true)
})
```

The second rotation effectively spins the pyramid around the *screen's* y-axis, not the pyramid's y-axis -- the one that goes through the apex of the pyramid. As you noted, it's spinning around what *was* the pyramid's y-axis as of before the first rotation; i.e. the y-axis of the scene (which is unaffected by physics), not that of the presentation node (that was rotated through physics).

To fix it, insert the following line (after the one that starts with `var axis`):

```
axis = scene.rootNode.convertPosition(axis, fromNode: node.presentationNode())
```

The call to [`convertPosition:fromNode:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/convertPosition:fromNode:) says "give me a vector in scene coordinate space that's equivalent to this one in presentation-node space". When you apply a torque around the converted axis, it effectively converts back to the presentation node's space to simulate physics, so you see it spin around the axis you want.

---

Update: Had some coordinate spaces wrong, but the end result is pretty much the same.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. Unfortunately does not work for me. I suspect it is because my objects are not in the center of my scene, and are not aligned to the World. I have a solution that works (posted) but I do not think it is pretty, accurate, or optimised.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, thanks! (Had to update some code to Swift 2 though, but no biggie.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the solution provided by rickster does not work for me :(

Trying to solve this conundrum I have created (what i believe to be) a very sub-standard solution (more a proof of concept). It involves creating (null) objects on the axis i am trying to find, then I use their position to find the vector aligned to the axes.

As I have a fairly complex scene, I am loading it from a COLLADA file. Within that file i have modelled a simple coordinate tripod: three orthogonal cylinders with cones on top (makes it easer to visualise what is going on).

I then constrain this tripod object to the object I am trying to apply torque to. This way I have objects that allow me to retrieve two points on the axes of the presentationNode of the object I am trying to apply torque to. I can then use these two points to determine the vector to apply the torque from.

```
// calculate orientation vector in the most unimaginative way possible

// retrieve axis tripod objects. We will be using these as guide objects.
// The tripod is constructed as a cylinder called "Xaxis" with a cone at the top.
// All loaded from an external COLLADA file.

SCNNode *XaxisRoot = [scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"XAxis" recursively:YES];
SCNNode *XaxisTip = [XaxisRoot childNodeWithName:@"Cone" recursively:NO];


// To devise the vector we will need two points. One is the root of our tripod,
// the other is at the tip. First, we get their positions. As they are constrained
// to the _rotatingNode, presentationNode.position is always the same .position
// because presentationNode returns position in relation to the parent node.

SCNVector3 XaxisRootPos = XaxisRoot.position;
SCNVector3 XaxisTipPos = XaxisTip.position;


// We then convert these two points into _rotatingNode coordinate space. This is
// the coordinate space applyTorque seems to be using.

XaxisRootPos = [_rotatingNode convertPosition:XaxisRootPos fromNode:_rotatingNode.presentationNode];
XaxisTipPos = [_rotatingNode convertPosition:XaxisTipPos fromNode:_rotatingNode.presentationNode];

// Now, we have two *points* in _rotatingNode coordinate space. One is at the center
// of our _rotatingNode, the other is somewhere along it's Xaxis. Subtracting them
// will give us the *vector* aligned to the x axis of our _rotatingNode

GLKVector3 rawXRotationAxes = GLKVector3Subtract(SCNVector3ToGLKVector3(XaxisRootPos), SCNVector3ToGLKVector3(XaxisTipPos));

// we now normalise this vector
GLKVector3 normalisedXRotationAxes = GLKVector3Normalize(rawXRotationAxes);

//finally we are able to apply toque reliably
[_rotatingNode.physicsBody applyTorque:SCNVector4Make(normalisedXRotationAxis.x,normalisedXRotationAxis.y,normalisedXRotationAxis.z, 500) impulse:YES];
```

As you can probably see, I am quite inexperienced in SceneKit, but even I can see that much easier/optimised solution does exits, but I am unable to find it :(

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same problem, of how to convert a torque from the local space of the object to the world space required by the `applyTorque` method. The problem with using the node's `convertPosition:toNode` and `fromNode`s methods, is that they are also applying the node's translation to the torque, so this will only work when the node is at 0,0,0. What these methods do is treat the SCNVector3 as if it's a vec4 with a w component of 1.0. We just want to apply the rotation, in other words, we want the w component of the vec4 to be 0. Unlike SceneKit, GLKit gives us 2 options for how we want our vec3s to be multiplied:

[GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3) where

> The input vector is treated as it were a 4-component vector with a w-component of 0.0.

and [GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3WithTranslation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3WithTranslation) where

> The input vector is treated as it were a 4-component vector with a w-component of 1.0.

What we want here is the former, just the rotation, not the translation.

So, we could roundtrip to GLKit. To convert for instance the local x axis (1,0,0), eg a pitch rotation, to the global axis needed for apply torque, would look like this:

```
    let local = GLKMatrix4MultiplyVector3(SCNMatrix4ToGLKMatrix4(node.presentationNode.worldTransform), GLKVector3(v: (1,0,0)))
    node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(local.x, local.y, local.z, 10), impulse: false)
```

However, a more Swiftian approach would be to add a `*` operator for mat4 * vec3 which treats the vec3 like a vec4 with a 0.0 w component. Like this:

```
func * (left: SCNMatrix4, right: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3 { //multiply mat4 by vec3 as if w is 0.0
    return SCNVector3(
        left.m11 * right.x + left.m21 * right.y + left.m31 * right.z,
        left.m12 * right.x + left.m22 * right.y + left.m32 * right.z,
        left.m13 * right.x + left.m23 * right.y + left.m33 * right.z
    )
}
```

Although this operator makes an assumption about how we want our vec3s to be multiplied, my reasoning here is that as the `convertPosition` methods already treat w as 1, it would be redundant to have a `*` operator that also did this.

You could also add a mat4 * SCNVector4 operator that would let the user explicity choose whether or not they want w to be 0 or 1.

So, instead of having to roundtrip from SceneKit to GLKit, we can just write:

```
    let local = node.presentationNode.worldTransform * SCNVector3(1,0,0)
    node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(local.x, local.y, local.z, 10), impulse: false)
```

You can use this method to apply rotation on multiple axes with one `applyTorque` call. So say if you have stick input where you want x on the stick to be yaw (local yUp-axis) and y on the stick to be pitch (local x-axis), but with flight-sim style "down to pull back/ up", then you could set it to `SCNVector3(input.y, -input.x, 0)`

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!

Comment: Although note that as of iOS 11, this gap in the SceneKit API was filled. There is now an `SCNNode.convertVector` method, which treats w as 0, whereas `SCNNode.convertPosition` treats w as 1: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2867403-convertvector

Comment: that's more convenient indeed, you are a star :), thank you!

Comment: I've not tested this, but it should be something like `let axisInWorldSpace = node.presentationNode.convertVector(SCNVector3(1, 0, 0), to: nil)`

Comment: Thanks again, it wasn't working and couldn't work out why until seeing your comment. I was using `node.convertVector` rather than `node.presentationNode.convertVector`

Now here is how I rotate the object along its Y axis.

`let local = node.presentation.convertVector(SCNVector3(0,1,0), to: nil)`
`node.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4(local.x, local.y, local.z, 0.2), asImpulse: false)
`